# Open API 3.0.0: referenced file cannot access parent components

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Using Open API 3.0.0, when main page is referencing a file as follow:

```
file: main.yaml
...
/ping:
    $ref: './dependency.yaml/#/foo'
...
components:
    responses:
        Response:
            type: string
```

And the dependency file is using the response from the main:

```
file: dependency.yaml
...
/ping:
    $ref: '#/components/responses/Response'
...
```

It do not work as he's only trying to resolve inside himself.
I've tried different way, unsuccessfully:

```
'..#/components/responses/Response'
'../#/components/responses/Response'
'#/../components/responses/Response'
```

Is there any way to do that ? I can't believe I have no other solutions than going with a huge file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using swagger-ui, when the ref is not in the main file, for exemple in `dep/foo.yaml` using `./` reference the current file. So here, `foo.yaml`.

So `../` is referencing `dep` folder.

Solution to access parent folder in a referenced file is `../../main.yaml`.

Comment: Hey, any clue why this does not work ?
`$ref: '../../swagger/references.yml#/components/schemas/User'`

Answer (score 1):

Any external `$ref` paths must include the file path. If `dependency.yaml` needs to reference `main.yaml`, the `$ref` should look like

```
$ref: './main.yaml#/components/responses/Response'
```

$refs do not have a concept of "parent"/"child" files, they are always resolved in the context of the current file.

Comment: I tried that too, but nested references are not handle